# Computer fails to boot from SSD

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, bios, bootloader

I have an Asus Zenbook UX393 that is unable to boot from any SSD, including the one it came with which was previously working (note that all SSDs involved are NVMe).

With the original SSD, which was working until recently (see below), and which has EndeavourOS installed, I cannot even access the BIOS as long as the SSD is present. When I try different SSDs with Windows installed, I get the Windows BSoD saying INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE. The computer then restarts and gives me the "Troubleshoot" and "Turn off your PC" options.

All SSDs work fine when I put them in other machines.

My computer *can* boot into a live USB. The problem is just with SSDs.

I have tried resetting the BIOS both through the menu option to do so and by disconnecting the battery and holding down the power button for 40 seconds. I have disabled fast boot. And I have upgraded the BIOS to the latest version.

The problem appeared after I was playing around with efibootmgr in Linux, trying to create a new boot option using EFISTUB. I feel strongly that my meddling with efibootmgr caused the problem. I believe the issue has to do with how the BIOS tries to boot from SSDs, and that I must have inadvertently changed some setting while using efibootmgr. If I could get the BIOS complete back to factory settings, I am hopeful the problem would be resolved.

After "resetting" the BIOS, I find that efibootmgr still sees boot entries that were defined before the reset, so it's clear to me that the reset did not actually reset everything. I think what I need is a more thorough way of resetting the BIOS.

Comment: We need more information about the machine and the SSD.

Comment: "Remember, I can't access BIOS when the drive is installed" - does the BIOS have a "fast boot" option? turn it off, then you should be able to get into BIOS using Del or F2 or whatever key is appropriate to your device

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks; I forgot to include in my post that I had tried that. Even with fastboot disabled, I cannot enter BIOS when I try to boot and this drive is installed.

Comment: @Ramhound What information do you need? The SSD is the one that came installed in the machine. I bought it refurbished so I don't know for sure if it's the factory original, but I think it is. It's an M.2 NVME PCIe x4. I could try to get some more info; what in particular is needed?

Comment: Your question makes no mention that this SSD came with the laptop. Your asking us to diagnose the reason your machine won’t boot while the SSD is installed. The first thing that comes to mind is the SSD is incompatible with your device.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. The SSD did come with the laptop and was working fine two days ago before I started messing around trying to learn more about EFI. The SSD is definitely compatible with the laptop. I have now established that the laptop will not boot from any SSD, but I can access files on SSDs from live USB drives.

Comment: @KayaFerendo - I have to ask. Was Windows installed in Legacy or UEFI mode?

Comment: @Ramhound All OSs were installed in UEFI mode.

I've pretty much convinced myself that I need to do something along the lines of resetting the nvram. But I'm not sure how to do that. dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nvram is giving me an input/output error.

Comment: Actually, I'm realizing that nvram seems to be something that Macs have, but not PCs. So I need to reset the PC analog I think. There seems to be some memory on the motherboard that is not getting reset when I reset the BIOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out there were two problems muddying the waters, but I was able to fix the primary one.

The two problems were that SSD1, which came with the computer and had EndeavourOS on it, would not boot, and that SSD2, which did not come with the computer and which had Windows 11 on it, would not boot. I have not solved "problem" 2 but I have no plans to use SSD2 with this computer, so it's not really a problem, just a strange behavior that arose in the course of troubleshooting.

To fix the problem with SSD1, I did the following (some of which may not be necessary).

1. I removed the SSD (necessary for the next step).
2. I booted into a Linux live USB
3. From the live USB, I used efibootmgr to remove all boot options.
4. I installed the SSD in a different machine and removed all efi files except for the one I knew worked.
5. I put the SSD back in the correct laptop and everything worked.

This is pretty common-sensical in hindsight, but some other issues were slowing me down from correctly implementing this solution.

I still don't know why the Windows drive doesn't boot in this computer (it does boot in the other laptop, and I know that the SSD itself is compatible with this laptop) but that doesn't really matter.

Comment: You really should stick with trying to find out these things 'cos these problems may present themselves at a later date with other things you want to boot

Comment: @barlop Yeah, it's a little ominous, isn't it? I don't really have the time or energy to experiment right now, but yeah, it would definitely be satisfying/reassuring to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: You could order a bunch of SSDs, very cheap to do.. and you might end up with a little collection of OSs or things to boot with them. Then you'll be in a good position to have another look at it some time in the future, or do a quick check of something.